# Link_to to make boolean true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to make a link to that changes a boolean, but have received error after error. I thought I had it figured out, but when i click the link `Couldn't find Clue with 'id'=Clue` and `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ClueController#update_clue1` appear. Thanks for all the help

my routes

```
resources :clue do
  member do
       get :update_clue1
       put :update_clue1
    end
end
```

Controller

```
def update_clue1
    @clue = Clue.find(params[:id])
    @clue.update_attributes(clue1: true)
    redirect_to "/home/clues"
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to "See next clue", update_clue1_clue_path(Clue), method: :put %>
```

Comment: `update_clue1_clue_path(Clue)` are you passing a Class? it should be the id of an object

Comment: I think @clue or Clue is the object.

Comment: yup so shouldnt it be `update_clue1_clue_path(@clue)`?

Comment: I just changed it and it said this `No route matches {:action=>"update_clue1", :controller=>"clue", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: thats because @clue is currently nil in your view. You need to set it to some Clue object first, which you should handle in the controller of that view

Comment: I think I have a clue object I have it in routes and a controller

Comment: Controller method responsible for generating the view needs to define `@clue` object and you need to use it in place of `Clue`, as pointed out by forthowin

Comment: Yes I get that I need to use it, but it creates an error.

Comment: If, in your view, you add `<% raise @clue.inspect %>`, you will probably see that `@clue` is `nil`. You need to set `@clue` in the action that is rendering the view with the link - not just in the `update_clue1` action.

Comment: What should define it as?

Comment: @JonEvans Because i'm trying to make all of the parts(ten booleans similar to this one) of `@clue` like `clue1` and then just have the users click change the value of booleans to true.

Comment: @user3312633 Is there one record in the database that you are trying to update ten attributes on? In other words, does each instance of `Clue` have, for example, the attributes `clue1`, `clue2`, `clue2`, etc? Or are you trying to update ten different `Clue` records?

Comment: I am updating them but a different times